# Mapear un array de objetos y segun el indice cambiar una propiedad

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo un array de arrays con objetos, con dos propiedades. Cada array dentro tiene una lista de objetos con tareas todos, con su contenido y su propiedad complete o en true o en false

```
  let list = [  
              [ { content: 'tareaOne', complete: true  },
                { content: 'tareaTwo', complete: false } 
                { content: 'tareaThree', complete: false } ],

              [ { content: 'tareaOne', complete: true  },
                { content: 'tareaTwo', complete: false } 
                { content: 'tareaThree', complete: false }
                { content: 'tareaFour', complete: false }
                { content: 'tareaFive', complete: false }
                                                          ],  
                                                            ]
```

Me pasan un variable index (que puede ir cambiando de valor, tengo otras cosas para hacer, pero para el ejemplo la dejo en 2)

```
let index = 2;
```

debo ingresar a cada array y segun el indice (que supongo que corresponde a la posicion de un objeto u otro) cambiarle la propiedad complete a true en caso de que sea false, si no que quede en true

Pense en utilizar map y recorrer cada elemento, comparar si el indice del mismo coincide con el de la variable y en un ternario cambiarle el valor a true, pero no se como usar el index de map y como podria complementar para abajar todo el recorrido del array

```
 lista.map((el,i) => i === parseInt(index) ? el[i].complete === true : false);
```

despues puedo devolver el objeto completo.. pero lo importante es entender lo anterior
gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: Con ese map sobre lista, solo estas recorriendo el primer array, el i es sobre el array lista, con lo que solo tienes dos elementos, tendrías que anidar otro map para acceder al array secundario.

Comment: `lista.map((el) =>{ el.map((ell,i) => i === parseInt(index) ? ell.complete === true : false);});` creo que esto es lo que quieres hacer.  recorres el primer array que contiene un segundo que lo recorres comparando el indice y cambiando todas las propiedades entre true y false.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que no necesitas complicarte tanto. Debido a que mencionas que siempre se debe modificar el valor de la tarea a `true` -sin importar si ya es `true`- lo único que resta por hacer es validar que ese índice exista ya que ni siquiera es necesario recorrer el segundo array puesto que es un valor fijo (entiendo por tu ejemplo que para los todos los arrays dentro de `list` cambiará solo la posición `index`), de ser así el valor de la propiedad `complete` para ese miembro pasará a ser true. Si no existe simplemente no sucederá nada -aunque igual podrías tratarlo como un error-.

**Edit 2:** Lo siguiente (el **Edit 1**) es tomando en cuenta que utilices la misma función y array para distintos valores de `index`. Si no es así, entonces no es necesario hacer una "copia" de `tasks`.

**Edit 1:** Parece ser que el truco del problema es saber tratar las modificaciones del objeto puesto que son tratadas como referencia por lo que debes buscar una manera para que esto no ocurra. En [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512418/why-does-array-map-not-return-a-new-array) y en [esta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) podrás encontrar más información acerca de cómo funcionan las referencias con objetos al momento de crear una copia y cómo "romper" esa referencia.

```js
  const list = [
  [
    { content: 'tareaOne', complete: true },
    { content: 'tareaTwo', complete: false },
    { content: 'tareaThree', complete: false }
  ],
  [
    { content: 'tareaOne', complete: true },
    { content: 'tareaTwo', complete: false },
    { content: 'tareaThree', complete: false },
    { content: 'tareaFour', complete: false },
    { content: 'tareaFive', complete: false }
  ]
]

function changeTaskStatus(index, array) {
  return array.map(tasks => {
    const newTasks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tasks));
    if (newTasks[index]) {
      newTasks[index].complete = true;
    }
    return newTasks;
  });
}

console.log(changeTaskStatus(2, list));
console.log(changeTaskStatus(0, list));
console.log(changeTaskStatus(4, list)); // En este ejemplo solo se verá afectado el segundo array dentro de list
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un array dentro de otro y un solo index, no creo que eso sea correcto.
Si el index que tienes se refiere a todos los arrays del primer nivel, osea todos los `tareaThree`, el map podría ser asi:

```js
  let list = [  
              [ { content: 'tareaOne', complete: true  },
                { content: 'tareaTwo', complete: false }, 
                { content: 'tareaThree', complete: false } ],

              [ { content: 'tareaOne', complete: true  },
                { content: 'tareaTwo', complete: false }, 
                { content: 'tareaThree', complete: false },
                { content: 'tareaFour', complete: false },
                { content: 'tareaFive', complete: false }
                                                          ],  
                                                            ]
                                                            
let index = 2;


list = list.map(e=>{
e[index].complete = true;
return e;
})


console.log(list)
```

Si tuvieras dos indices no sería necesario una iteración:

```
list[index1][index2].complete = true;
```